# Windows universal app certification never finishes

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, app-certification-kit

I've developed a simple application that builds, compiles and run flawesslly in my computer and its emulators.

The problem is that the app certification test stuck for hours at 50% approximately and never finishes. I've compiled the app with and without the option ".NET native tool chain".

Has anyone been trought this? How can I get my app tested?
[image: print screen]

Comment: You definitely need native tool chain enabled. The program you're running is really buggy, I've had issues in the past with it. I think your best bet is to submit to Microsoft Store. They will tell you if anything is bad.

Comment: I always prefer ".NET native tool chain" activated. I can't submit to Microsoft Store because I need the test finished to get the ".appxupload" file. Is there a way to generate this file without passing through "appcertui.exe"?

Comment: Yes. In Visual Studio solution explorer, right-click the project file and go to Store->Create App Packages.

Comment: Yes it does. For example I have a UWP app called Car Selector. Look in file explorer after it finishes in your projects root directory for a file call AppPackages. My path is C:\Users\skitc\OneDrive\Documents\SethKitchenTFS\HE\SandBox\Coop\Windows10UniversalApp\CarSelector\CarSelector\AppPackages Inside there is a _Test Folder. Inside there is CarSelector_1.0.33.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle

Comment: My bad. It does create. But I can't start the "appcert.exe" through Visual Studio cause the file disappears.

Comment: Did you finally solve it?